C++ 20 Concept no longer compiles after upgrading from GCC11.4 to GCC12.3
The following is a simplified example of some code which has been compiling find using MSVC and  GCC11.4 for x64 & AARCH64:
#include <stop_token>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename TOwner>
concept HasGetStopToken = requires(TOwner& o) {
    { o.GetStopToken() } -> std::same_as<std::stop_token>;
};

template <typename TOwner>
class RequestLooper
{
public:

    explicit RequestLooper(TOwner& _owner)
        requires HasGetStopToken<TOwner>
        : m_owner{ _owner }
    {
    }

private:
    TOwner& m_owner;
};

class CoreApplication {

public:
    std::stop_token GetStopToken() { return m_stopSource.get_token(); }

    using Looper = RequestLooper<CoreApplication>;

    CoreApplication() : m_looper{*this}
    {
    }

private:
    Looper m_looper;
    std::stop_source m_stopSource;
};

The compiler has recently been upgraded to g++12.3 and the code no longer compiles, it fails with:
In instantiation of 'RequestLooper<TOwner>::RequestLooper(TOwner&) requires  HasGetStopToken<TOwner> [with TOwner = CoreApplication]':
<source>:31:25:   required from here
<source>:5:9:   required for the satisfaction of 'HasGetStopToken<TOwner>' [with TOwner = CoreApplication]
<source>:5:27:   in requirements with 'TOwner& o' [with TOwner = CoreApplication]
<source>:5:27: error: satisfaction value of atomic constraint 'requires(TOwner& o) {{o->GetStopToken()} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::same_as<<placeholder>, std::stop_token>];} [with TOwner = CoreApplication]' changed from 'false' to 'true'
    5 | concept HasGetStopToken = requires(TOwner& o) {
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    6 |     { o.GetStopToken() } -> std::same_as<std::stop_token>;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    7 | };
      | ~                          
<source>:10:7: note: satisfaction value first evaluated to 'false' from here
   10 | class RequestLooper
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In constructor 'CoreApplication::CoreApplication()':
<source>:31:25: error: no matching function for call to 'RequestLooper<CoreApplication>::RequestLooper(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   31 |     CoreApplication() : m_looper{*this}
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:14:14: note: candidate: 'RequestLooper<TOwner>::RequestLooper(TOwner&) requires  HasGetStopToken<TOwner> [with TOwner = CoreApplication]'
   14 |     explicit RequestLooper(TOwner& _owner)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:14:14: note: constraints not satisfied
<source>:10:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr RequestLooper<CoreApplication>::RequestLooper(const RequestLooper<CoreApplication>&)'
   10 | class RequestLooper
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'CoreApplication' to 'const RequestLooper<CoreApplication>&'
<source>:10:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr RequestLooper<CoreApplication>::RequestLooper(RequestLooper<CoreApplication>&&)'
<source>:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'CoreApplication' to 'RequestLooper<CoreApplication>&&'
Compiler returned: 1

Using compiler explorer (https://godbolt.org/) I can confirm that the code compiles correctly using g++11.4, g++12.1, g++12.2, g++13.1 etc.
It fails with g++12.3 and g++12.4 so it loks as if the issue is with the compiler and not the code.
Is this a known compiler bug?
Unfortunately the compiler I have is g++12.3 running on Ubuntu22_04.
I can find a workaround for installing g++13 (along with the aarch64 cross compiler version) under wsl (see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490387/how-do-i-install-the-gcc-13-aarch64-cross-compiler-on-ubuntu-22-04) but when I tried it on the build machine it wanted to update glibc which I am loathe to do.
Is there a straight forward way to update to gcc13 on Ubuntu22_04?
Alternatively is there a workaround that does not require the removal of the concept?

Newest gcc has a bug fix. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/68521370/817643 for example - This was not meant to work.
